# Incorrect number of binding when trying to delete from a database (Tkinter, SQLite)

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, ttk

I have been doing an interface in Python that can add, edit and delete elements from a database and show said database in a ttk treeview. Right now I'm stuck at the function `elimina_Registro`, which is supposed to delete an item from the database and update the treeview when the `boton_eliminar` button is pressed. When I do press the button to call the function, I get an error message that says `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.` which is weird because the only binding I'm providing is `self.entry_Id.get()`.

Here's the complete code:

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
import sqlite3

class ProyectoPooApp:

    #Conexión base de datos
    nombre_db = r'datebase_POO.db'
    with sqlite3.connect(nombre_db) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            
    actualiza = None
    
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # Build ui
        self.win = tk.Tk() if master is None else tk.Toplevel(master)

        #Función centrar pantalla
        app_w=1147
        app_h=379
        screen_w = self.win.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_h = self.win.winfo_screenheight()
        x= (screen_w/2)-(app_w/2)
        y=(screen_h/2)- (app_h/2)
        self.win.geometry(f'{app_w}x{app_h}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

        self.win.configure(background="#dafcfc")
        self.win.iconbitmap("icono.ico")
        self.win.resizable(False, False)
        self.win.title("Conferencia Arquitectura Hexagonal")

        self.frame_datos = ttk.Frame(self.win)

        #Frame Iscripción
        self.frame_inscripcion = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame_datos, font= ("Helvetica", 13,"bold"))
        self.frame_inscripcion
        self.frame_inscripcion.configure(
            labelanchor="n",
            relief="groove",
            text='Inscripción')
        
        #Label identificacion
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.label1.configure(state="normal", text='Identificación')
        self.label1.grid(column=0, padx="20 10", pady="20 20", row=0, sticky="e")

        #Label nombre
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.label2.configure(text='Nombre\t')
        self.label2.grid(column=0, padx="20 10", pady="0 20", row=1, sticky="e")

        #Label direccion
        self.label3 = ttk.Label(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.label3.configure(text='Dirección')
        self.label3.grid(column=0, padx="20 10", pady="0 20", row=2, sticky="e")

        #Label celular
        self.label4 = ttk.Label(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.label4.configure(text='Celular')
        self.label4.grid(column=0, padx="20 10", pady="0 20", row=3, sticky="e")

        #Label entidad
        self.label5 = ttk.Label(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.label5.configure(text='Entidad')
        self.label5.grid(column=0, padx="20 10", pady="0 20", row=4, sticky="e")

        #Label fecha
        self.label6 = ttk.Label(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.label6.configure(text='Fecha')
        self.label6.grid(column=0, padx="20 10", pady="0 20", row=5, sticky="e")

        #Entry Identificacion
        self.entry_id = ttk.Entry(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.entry_id.configure(width=33)
        self.entry_id.grid(column=1, padx="0 20", pady="20 20", row=0)

        #Entry nombre
        self.entry_nombre = ttk.Entry(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.entry_nombre.configure(width=33)
        self.entry_nombre.grid(column=1, padx="0 20", pady="0 20", row=1)

        #Entry dirección
        self.entry_direccion = ttk.Entry(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.entry_direccion.configure(width=33)
        self.entry_direccion.grid(column=1, padx="0 20", pady="0 20", row=2)

        #Entry celular
        self.entry_celular = ttk.Entry(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.entry_celular.configure(width=33)
        self.entry_celular.grid(column=1, padx="0 20", pady="0 20", row=3)

        #Entry entidad
        self.entry_entidad = ttk.Entry(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.entry_entidad.configure(width=33)
        self.entry_entidad.grid(column=1, padx="0 20", pady="0 20", row=4)

        #Entry fecha
        self.entry_fecha = ttk.Entry(self.frame_inscripcion)
        self.entry_fecha.configure(width=33)
        self.entry_fecha.grid(column=1, padx="0 20", pady="0 20", row=5)

        #Frame botones
        self.frame_inscripcion.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.frame_botones = ttk.Frame(self.frame_datos)
        self.frame_botones.configure(height=200, width=200)

        #Boton grabar
        self.boton_grabar = ttk.Button(self.frame_botones)
        self.boton_grabar.configure(
            cursor="hand2", default="normal", text='Grabar')
        self.boton_grabar.grid(column=0, padx="0 5", row=0)
        self.boton_grabar.bind("<1>", self.adiciona_Registro, add="+")

        #Boton editar
        self.boton_editar = ttk.Button(self.frame_botones)
        self.boton_editar.configure(cursor="hand2", text='Editar')
        self.boton_editar.grid(column=1, padx="5 5", row=0)
        self.boton_editar.bind("<1>", self.edita_tablaTreeView, add="+")
        
        #Boton eliminar
        self.boton_eliminar = ttk.Button(self.frame_botones)
        self.boton_eliminar.configure(cursor="hand2", text='Eliminar')
        self.boton_eliminar.grid(column=2, padx="5 5", row=0)
        self.boton_eliminar.bind("<1>", self.elimina_Registro, add="+")
        
        #Boton cancelar
        self.boton_cancelar = ttk.Button(self.frame_botones)
        self.boton_cancelar.configure(cursor="hand2", text='Cancelar', command= self.limpia_Campos)
        self.boton_cancelar.grid(column=3, padx="5 0", row=0, sticky="e")
        
        self.frame_botones.grid(column=0, pady="10 0", row=1)
        self.frame_datos.grid(column=0, pady="30 0", row=0, sticky="n")

        #Frame treeview
        self.frame_treeview = ttk.Frame(self.win)

        #Scrollbar treeview
        self.scroll_treeview = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_treeview)
        self.scroll_treeview.configure(orient="vertical")
        self.scroll_treeview.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")

        self.style=ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure("estilo.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, background='AliceBlue', fieldbackground="Aliceblue", font=('Helvetica',10))
        self.style.configure("estilo.Treeview.Heading", background='Azure', font=('Helvetica', 10,'bold'))
        self.style.map("estilo.treeview", background =[('selected', "Steelblue")])
        self.style.layout("estilo.Treeview", [('estilo.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})])

        #Treeview
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.frame_treeview, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_treeview.set, style = "estilo.Treeview")
        self.scroll_treeview.config(command=self.treeview.yview)
        self.treeview.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.edita_tablaTreeView, add="+")

        self.treeview.configure(
            height=15,
            selectmode="browse",
            show="headings")
        self.treeview_cols = [
            'columna_id',
            'columna_nombre',
            'columna_direccion',
            'columna_celular',
            'columna_entidad',
            'columna_fecha']
        self.treeview_dcols = [
            'columna_id',
            'columna_nombre',
            'columna_direccion',
            'columna_celular',
            'columna_entidad',
            'columna_fecha']
        self.treeview.configure(
            columns=self.treeview_cols,
            displaycolumns=self.treeview_dcols)
        
        #Columna id
        self.treeview.column(
            "columna_id",
            anchor="w",
            stretch="true",
            width=120,
            minwidth=20)
        
        #Columna nombre
        self.treeview.column(
            "columna_nombre",
            anchor="w",
            stretch="true",
            width=120,
            minwidth=20)
        
        #Columna direccion
        self.treeview.column(
            "columna_direccion",
            anchor="w",
            stretch="true",
            width=120,
            minwidth=20)
        
        #Columna celular
        self.treeview.column(
            "columna_celular",
            anchor="w",
            stretch="true",
            width=120,
            minwidth=20)
        
        #Columna entidad
        self.treeview.column(
            "columna_entidad",
            anchor="w",
            stretch="true",
            width=120,
            minwidth=20)
        
        #Columna fecha
        self.treeview.column(
            "columna_fecha",
            anchor="w",
            stretch="true",
            width=120,
            minwidth=20)
        
        #Nombres columnas
        self.treeview.heading(
            "columna_id", 
            anchor="center", 
            text='Id')
        
        self.treeview.heading(
            "columna_nombre", 
            anchor="center", 
            text='Nombre')
        
        self.treeview.heading(
            "columna_direccion",
            anchor="center",
            text='Dirección')
        
        self.treeview.heading(
            "columna_celular",
            anchor="center",
            text='Celular')
        
        self.treeview.heading(
            "columna_entidad",
            anchor="center",
            text='Entidad')
        
        self.treeview.heading(
            "columna_fecha", 
            anchor="center", 
            text='Fecha')
        
        self.treeview.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.frame_treeview.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.win.rowconfigure(0, pad=40)
        self.win.columnconfigure(0, pad=40)
        self.win.columnconfigure(1, pad=40)

             
        # Main widget
        self.mainwindow = self.win
        self.lee_tablaTreeView()

    def valida(self):
        return (len(self.entry_id.get()) != 0 )

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()

    def valida_Identificacion(self, event=None):
      pass

    def valida_Fecha(self, event=None):
      pass
    

    def carga_Datos(self, values):
        self.entry_id.insert(0, values[0])
        self.entry_nombre.insert(0, values[1])
        self.entry_direccion.insert(0, values[2])
        self.entry_celular.insert(0, values[3])
        self.entry_entidad.insert(0, values[4])
        self.entry_fecha.insert(0, values[5])    
              
    def limpia_Campos(self):
      self.actualiza = None
      self.entry_id.configure(state = tk.NORMAL)
      self.entry_id.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.entry_nombre.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.entry_direccion.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.entry_celular.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.entry_entidad.delete(0, tk.END)
      self.entry_fecha.delete(0, tk.END)


    def run_Query(self, query, parametros = ()):
        #Función para ejecutar los Querys a la base de datos
        result = self.cursor.execute(query, parametros)
        self.conn.commit()
        return result 

    def lee_tablaTreeView(self):
        self.treeview.delete(*self.treeview.get_children())

        query = 'SELECT rowid, * FROM Asistentes'
        self.run_Query(query)
        registros = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for record in registros:
                self.treeview.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=record[0], text='', values=(record[0], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6]))
        self.conn.commit()

    def adiciona_Registro(self, event=None):
        #Adiciona un producto a la base de datos
        if self.actualiza:
            self.actualiza = None
            query = 'UPDATE Asistentes SET Id = ?, Nombre = ?, Dirección = ?, Celular = ?, Entidad = ?, Fecha = ? WHERE Id = ?'
            parametros = (self.entry_id.get(), self.entry_nombre.get(), self.entry_direccion.get(),
                          self.entry_celular.get(), self.entry_entidad.get(), self.entry_fecha.get(), self.entry_id.get())
            self.run_Query(query, parametros)
            msg.showinfo('Ok',' Registro actualizado con éxito')
        else:
            query = 'INSERT INTO Asistentes VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parametros = (self.entry_id.get(), self.entry_nombre.get(), self.entry_direccion.get(),
                          self.entry_celular.get(), self.entry_entidad.get(), self.entry_fecha.get())
            if self.valida():
                self.run_Query(query, parametros)
                msg.showinfo('',f'Registro: {self.entry_id.get()} agregado')
                self.limpia_Campos()
            else:
                msg.showerror("¡Atención!","No puede dejar la identificación vacía")
        self.limpia_Campos()
        self.lee_tablaTreeView()
        self.entry_id.configure(state = tk.NORMAL)

    def edita_tablaTreeView(self, event=None):

        try:
            seleccion = self.treeview.focus()
            parametros = self.treeview.item(seleccion, 'values')
            self.limpia_Campos()

            self.actualiza = True # Esta variable controla la actualización
            self.carga_Datos(parametros)
            self.entry_id.configure(state = 'readonly')

        except IndexError as error:
            self.actualiza = None
            msg.showerror("¡Atención!",'Por favor seleccione un ítem de la tabla')
            return
        
    def elimina_Registro(self, event=None):
     #Elimina un producto de la base de datos
        if self.actualiza:
            self.actualiza = None
            elemento = self.treeview.selection()[0]
            query = 'DELETE FROM Asistentes WHERE Id = ?'
            parametros = (self.entry_id.get())
            opcion = msg.askokcancel('¡Atención!', '¿Borrar registro?')
            if opcion:
                self.treeview.delete(elemento)
                self.run_Query(query, parametros)
                msg.showinfo('',f'Registro: {self.entry_id.get()} eliminado')
            else: msg.showinfo('', 'No se eliminó el registro')
        else:
            msg.showerror("¡Atención!","Debe seleccionar un registro")
        self.limpia_Campos()
        self.lee_tablaTreeView()
        self.entry_id.configure(state = tk.NORMAL)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ProyectoPooApp()
    app.run()
```

I was expecting for it to simply delete the item and update the treeview. As the only condition I'm providing is that it has to have the requested Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma in `parametros = (self.entry_id.get())`, that's because in Python `("foo") == "foo"`, to create a tuple of one element you should use `("foo",)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood right, so I should add a comma inside the parentheses right before ´self.entry_id.get()´, or after?

Comment: After, just like this `(´self.entry_id.get(),)`.